# Sbt working with child projects

Tags: scala, sbt

For example, I have projects Child1, Child2, ChildN and Parent. I want to be able to invoke any public method in any child project from "Parent" project. I supposed that [sbt's ParentProject](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/SubProjects) will handle my issues but it even don't have "run" action.

What sbt configuration will handle my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a default project, like this, and `run` will be available:

```
import sbt._

class TopProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {

  /* subprojects */

  lazy val proj1 = project("subdir" / "proj1")
  lazy val proj2 = project("subdir" / "proj2")

}
```